# Add packages from requirements.txt to Docker image to minimize cold start time on EC2?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, docker-machine

When deploying a machine learning model on EC2 from a Docker image, the cold start time is high because the instance downloads the packages and files from `requirements.txt` even though the dockerfile contains `pip install` to install all these packages.

Some sample output when booting up:

```
021-11-21 05:28:57.632740:cortex:pid-1:INFO:downloading the project code
2021-11-21 05:28:57.746448:cortex:pid-1:INFO:downloading the python serving image
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Collecting imutils
  Downloading imutils-0.5.4.tar.gz (17 kB)
Collecting tensorflow==2.4.1
  Downloading tensorflow-2.4.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (394.3 MB)
Collecting opencv-python==4.1.2.30
  Downloading opencv_python-4.1.2.30-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.3 MB)
Collecting pillow==7.0.0
  Downloading Pillow-7.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting flask-cors==3.0.8
  Downloading Flask_Cors-3.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in /opt/conda/envs/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /mnt/project/requi
rements.txt (line 6)) (1.13.7)
Collecting torch==1.8.1+cu101
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.8.1%2Bcu101-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl (763.6 MB)
Collecting torchvision==0.9.1+cu101
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torchvision-0.9.1%2Bcu101-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl (17.3 MB)
```

Rather than download and install these files for each EC2 instance launched, is it possible to do this once and incorporate the files into the Docker image during the Docker build process?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.4.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    ffmpeg \
    libsm6 \
    libxext6 \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ADD ./requirements.txt ./

# install our dependencies
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ADD ./ ./

ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080","--log-level", "debug"]
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
torch==1.9.0
ffmpeg_python==0.1.17
fastai==1.0.51
boto3==1.18.15
botocore==1.21.15
scikit_image==0.17.2
requests==2.26.0
torchvision==0.10.0
opencv_python==4.5.3.56
starlette==0.14.2
scipy==1.5.4
numpy==1.19.5
fastapi==0.68.0
ffmpeg==1.4
ipython==7.16.1
Pillow==8.3.1
tensorboardX==2.4
uvicorn
python-multipart
youtube_dl==2021.6.6
uvloop
```

Comment: Yes (`RUN pip install` during the Docker build); most Python Dockerfiles I've seen work this way.

Comment: @DavidMaze the dockerfile does contain `pip install` yet this still occurs when launching the EC2 instance

Comment: @DavidMaze updated the question with the dockerfile

Comment: How are you actually running the container, then?  If you have a CI system run `docker build` and push it to a registry like Docker Hub or ECR, the instance should be able to just run it, without rebuilding.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the reply. we push it to amazon ECR, and it pulls from there yet somehow the output suggests it's repeating the download/installation process for `requirements.txt`.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks again for helping. just want to follow up in case you didn't see the reply to your comment.

Comment: Provide some more details on how you use the ECR image and start your application. Is ECR the only AWS service you are using? Are you also using batch? Also in your docker command you have uvicorn, but I don't see it in the requirements.

Comment: @kgiannakakis sorry, updated with the correct `requirements.txt` file. we pull the ECR image onto a EC2 instance. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think,

### AS-IS:

(Local)

write code and Docker

=> push remote git-server

(EC2)

pull git repo

=> run Dockerfile

### TO-BE:

(Local)

write code and Docker

=> push remote git-server

=> build Docker Image (by github-action or manually)

=> push Docker Image to Container Registry (by github-action or manually)

(EC2)

pull Docker Image

=>run Docker Image

Answer (score 1):

Doing some guesswork from the info you are providing, it seems that you are using [Cortex](https://docs.cortex.dev/workloads/batch/example) to deploy your workloads. You try to preinstall your python dependencies in your container, so that you don't have to manually download them every time your container start. The logs files come from your application inside the container. Although you have already installed them in the container OS, Cortex most probably uses [virtual environments](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) to separate jobs and downloads requirements again. This is how virtual environments work and it is actually the only way the EC2 images could support different jobs, with different requirements each.

Provide some more details to get any further assistance.

Comment: Thanks! We are using Cortex. Are you saying there's nothing more we can do to minimize boot time?

Comment: There could be a way, but you aren't asking the right question. This has to do with how Cortex is setting up the "python serving image" and if there is a way to speed this up.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Cortex experience and have very low availability at the moment anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a true answer but I hope it will be of help.

According to the error trace you provided in your question, and as pointed out as well in other answers, you seem to be using Cortex.

Please, consider review [this Github issue](https://github.com/cortexlabs/cortex/issues/1827). It describes the behavior you are indicating. Consider especially the [first comment from  David Eliahu](https://github.com/cortexlabs/cortex/issues/1827#issuecomment-767315704):

> "downloading the python serving image" refers to downloading the docker image for the API.
>
> By default, the image is hosted on quay.io, and likely has dependencies
> installed which you do not need. So, the best way to speed this up is to
> make the image smaller, and host the image on ECR in the same region as
> your cluster (assuming you're running on AWS). Here is our documentation
> for both of these approaches: https://docs.cortex.dev/workloads/managing-dependencies/images

The provided link is broken, although the colocated image approach is still suggested in the product [Production Guide](https://docs.cortex.dev/clusters/management/production#use-images-from-a-colocated-ecr) and especially in [this article](https://docs.cortex.dev/clusters/advanced/self-hosted-images).

Unfortunately, it only provides advice about how to minimize the image pull time but it says nothing about how to speed up the actual container boot process.

The aforementioned issue talks about optimizing the image making it smaller but it seems no longer described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is indeed useful.

Comment: You are welcome @Crashalot. I hope it helps.

Comment: It did. You don't happen to have any advice for this problem, do you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162157/fastapi-or-starlette-substantial-latency-added-after-call-next-function-in-midd

Comment: @Crashalot I am happy to hear that the response was helpful. Regarding your new question, it may be related to Starlette. Please, consider review [this other GitHub issue](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2241). At the very end it could provide alternatives to your current implementation [like using other middleware](https://github.com/steinnes/timing-asgi). I hope it helps as well.

Comment: Understood. Could you help with this possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70162157/fastapi-or-starlette-substantial-latency-added-after-call-next-function-in-midd

Comment: Thank you very much @Crashalot. Yes, please, see my previous comment, it was related to that question.